# Hall effect sensor through plastic

Tags: motor, dc-motor, hall-effect

I was wondering about the viability of adding a Hall effect sensor which can sense a magnet through a plastic cover.

I'm interested measuring the angular velocity of a motor through a plastic cover, my plan is to mount magnets to the drive gear:

[image]

And attach a Hall sensor outside the cover:

[image]

But I'm not sure if the distance will be too great or the motors will impact sensor reading.

Any ideas?

My end goal is having the chassis be controlled by a Raspberry Pi or Jetson Nano but I'm not sure if they will keep up with the sample requirements so I'm thinking of running a separate Arduino to actually count rotations and be fed target velocities and return total rotations between samples.

Comment: For the  "sample requirements," look into timers and interrupts.  There's no reason why measuring the RPM should be a problem on a Pi or a Jetson Nano - or an Arduino Nano for that fact.  If you are sampling an analog input, then you will have a problem with the load.  If you use a digital input, an interrupt, and a timer, then your processor won't even notice the load.  Consider that 10000 RPM is only 166.7 rotatations per second.

Comment: The issue is the nano and pi are not real time, maybe GPIO ISR will work correctly - I am not sure. I do know people say to use a separate PWM motor driver for other projects with the nano. Also have any idea what the best way to mount the magnets would be? I'm slightly worried that simple glue will result in them coming loose and destroying the gearbox. I thought about enlarging a couple of the holes and trying to find magnets which were small enough to be embedded but I am not sure if it will work.

Comment: Have a look here for magnetic encoders: https://www.rls.si/en/onaxis . You may find also similar ones on ebay, ali, ...